# Ubuntu 18.04 immediately logs out with a specific user

Tags: 18.04, login, crash, logout, indicator-multiload

My Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't allow me to log in with GNOME. Immediately after logging in, it seems that a crash occurs and I'm back at the log in page. If I try with a different user it works.

I found this in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Dec 10 10:13:38 y-server indicator-multi[13236]: indicator-multiload: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.*
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to uninstall the indicator-multiload and now everything is working fine. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Yes! This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, me too. It actually logged me out right after I installed it.